# How added dynamically Textarea from TinyMCE in java script

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

i am not able to add text area dynamically from java script ,any solutions pls would help me

function createRTEforDocuments(controlName){
try{
if(tinymce.get(controlName)){       //If there is any existing instance of that specific RTE
tinymce.remove("#"+controlName);
}

```
    tinymce.init({
        max_height: 900,
        selector: 'textarea#'+controlName,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: 'searchreplace autolink image link table advlist lists',
        toolbar: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | forecolor backcolor formatpainter | link image | \
        alignleft aligncenter alignjustify | numlist bullist | table | removeformat',
        image_advtab: true,
        paste_data_images: true,
        setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('init', function(e) {
                        console.log('The Editor has initialized.');
                        
                        //Setting saved data
                        let formData = edoras.currentState.formData.get();
                        if(!!formData[controlName])
                            tinymce.get(controlName).setContent(formData[controlName]);
                        
                        //Code to prevent Copy-Paste of large image files
                        tinymce.get(controlName).on('paste',(e)=> {
                            let copiedData = e.clipboardData.items;
                            for(var i=0; i< copiedData.length; i++){
                                let blob = e.clipboardData.items[i].getAsFile();
                                if(!!blob && blob.type.includes('image') && blob.size > 1000000){
                                    edoras.ui.globalMessage.show("The image exceeded the maximum allowed size. Please retry with size less than 1 MB.", "error",5000);
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    console.log(blob);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        },true);
                        
                        //Code to prevent Drag-Drop of large image files
                        tinymce.get(controlName).on("drop",(e)=> {
                            let copiedData = e.dataTransfer.files;
                            for(var i=0; i< copiedData.length; i++){
                                let blob = copiedData[i];
                                if(!!blob && blob?.type?.includes('image') && blob.size > 1000000){
                                    edoras.ui.globalMessage.show("The image exceeded the maximum allowed size. Please retry with size less than 1 MB.", "error",5000);
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    console.log(blob);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        },true);
                        
                        //On change, save the data in variable
                        tinymce.get(controlName).on("change", function() {
                            console.log('Tiny MCE On Change occured on '+ controlName);
                            try {
                                $(tinymce.get(controlName).getBody()).find('img').css('width', '100%').css('height', '100%');
                                edoras.currentState.formData.set(controlName, tinyMCE.get(controlName).getContent());
                            } catch (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            }

                        });

                    })}
    });
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
```

}